# react native conditional rendering swipeout listitem

Tags: react-native, conditional-statements, rendering, state

Hi So I'm trying to add a functionality that allows user to delete an item from a a flat list , based of the criteria that they created it. My check is  `if (id.user[0].name === item)`

At the moment they either all have the 'Delete' swipe or none of them do.

I am wondering is it even possible the method I'm using trying to alter the state of Swipeout.

```
 renderItem(item) {
const { id } = this.state;

const swipeBtns = [
  {
    text: 'Delete',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    underlayColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1, 0.6)',
    onPress: () => {
      this.deleteNote(item);
    },
  },
];

return (
  <Swipeout
    right={swipeBtns}
    autoClose="true"
    backgroundColor="transparent"
    disabled={this.state.swipeState}
  >
    <ListItem
      onPress={() => this.toggleModalConfirmTrip(item)}
      roundAvatar
      subtitle={item.user[0].name}
      title={`${item.location_from} to ${item.location_to} `}
      rightTitle={item.timeStamp}
      avatar={
        <Image
          source={require('../assests/carLogo.png')}
          style={{ width: 40, height: 50, borderRadius: 10 }}
        />
      }
      containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0, paddingBottom: 10 }}
    />
  </Swipeout>
);
```

}

```
  renderSwipe = item => {
const { id } = this.state;
this.setState({ item, swipeState: false });
console.warn(item, id);
if (id === item) {
  this.setState({ swipeState: false });
} else {
  this.setState({ swipeState: true });
}
```

};

My question is where do I run this renderSwipe function or is there another way that I can enable swipe on some items and disable on it others based off of the condition above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is possible to do it in your renderItem function, so you may not require the renderSwipe function.

You may have been having problems with `state` as you have been setting it is for the whole component. So when you set `swipeState` to false every item in the list will have the swipeState equal to false.

The SwipeOut has a prop called `disabled` setting this value to true will disable the swipe functionality. Then all you have to do is make a check there for your condition.

So something like this should do the trick.

```
<SwipeOut
  ...
  disabled={id.user[0].name !== item} 
>
```

So when `id.user[0].name !== item` is true the swipe will be disabled, and when it is false the swipe will be enabled.

Just make sure that you are comparing the right things. I have a feeling you may wish to be comparing `id.user[0].name !== item.user[0].name`

Comment: I didn't know you could simply pass the conditional in the prop! That works thanks. so much. FYI I was comparing the right thing I just didn't do it in the right place :)

Comment: That's great that it worked. If you are happy with the answer please mark it as correct :)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to do so unfortunately!

Comment: You don't have enough reputation to upvote but you should be able to mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow